# Yocto recipe to overwrite files from another recipe

Tags: yocto

I need to overwrite the shared libraries built from a given recipe (let's call it packageX) with libraries built from my custom recipe. Basically, I need to build and generate `libA.so` and `libB.so` in `/usr/lib` from packageX. After that, my recipe should generate the custom `libA.so` and `libB.so`, among other libraries that will be added.

I tried to create a custom recipe that generates the needed libraries, but they cannot be written over the original libraries.

```
ERROR: my_recipe-1.0.0-r0 do_populate_sysroot: The recipe my_recipe is trying to install files into a shared area when those files already exist.
Those files and their manifest location are:
.../usr/lib/libA.so.1.0.0
Matched in b'manifest-packageX.populate_sysroot'
.../usr/lib/libB.so.1.0.0
Matched in b'manifest-packageX.populate_sysroot'
Please verify which recipe should provide the above files.
ERROR: my_recipe-1.0.0-r0 do_populate_sysroot: If the above message is too much, the simpler version is you're advised to wipe out tmp and rebuild (reusing sstate is fine). That will likely fix things in most (but not all) cases.
```

After that, I tried to change the `packageX` recipe:

```
PACKAGES =+ "libC libD libE"
FILES_libC = "${libdir}/libC${SOLIBS}"
FILES_libD = "${libdir}/libD${SOLIBS}"
FILES_libE = "${libdir}/libE${SOLIBS}"

# compile function will build the libraries

do_install_append_class-target () {
    install -Dm 0755 ${S}/my_recipe/bin/libA.so ${D}${libdir}/libA.so.1.0.0
    install -Dm 0755 ${S}/my_recipe/bin/libB.so ${D}${libdir}/libB.so.1.0.0
    install -Dm 0755 ${S}/my_recipe/bin/libC.so ${D}${libdir}/libC.so.1.0.0
    install -Dm 0755 ${S}/my_recipe/bin/libD.so ${D}${libdir}/libD.so.1.0.0
    install -Dm 0755 ${S}/my_recipe/bin/libE.so ${D}${libdir}/libE.so.1.0.0
    oe_libinstall -so libA ${D}${libdir}
    oe_libinstall -so libB ${D}${libdir}
    oe_libinstall -so libC ${D}${libdir}
    oe_libinstall -so libD ${D}${libdir}
    oe_libinstall -so libE ${D}${libdir}
}
```

And the output is:

```
ERROR: packageX-1.0.2j-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: packageX path '.../packageX/1.0.2j-r0/packages-split/packageX/usr/lib/libA.so'
non -dev/-dbg/nativesdk- package contains symlink .so: packageX path '.../packageX/1.0.2j-r0/packages-split/packageX/usr/lib/libB.so' [dev-so]
ERROR: packageX-1.0.2j-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: No GNU_HASH in the elf binary: '.../packageX/1.0.2j-r0/packages-split/libC/usr/lib/libC.so.1.0.0' [ldflags]
ERROR: packageX-1.0.2j-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: No GNU_HASH in the elf binary: '.../packageX/1.0.2j-r0/packages-split/libE/usr/lib/libE.so.1.0.0' [ldflags]
WARNING: packageX-1.0.2j-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libE.so.1.0.0 contained in package libE requires libD.so, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libE? [file-rdeps]
ERROR: packageX-1.0.2j-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: No GNU_HASH in the elf binary: '.../packageX/1.0.2j-r0/packages-split/libD/usr/lib/libD.so.1.0.0' [ldflags]
WARNING: packageX-1.0.2j-r0 do_package_qa: QA Issue: /usr/lib/libD.so.1.0.0 contained in package libD requires libC.so, but no providers found in RDEPENDS_libD? [file-rdeps]
```

Conclusion: my goal is to overwrite those libraries from Yocto recipes. Keeping the `packageX` recipe untouched would be perfect. So how can I achieve this from Yocto recipes?

Comment: You need to write bbappend for the original recipe, not a new recipe: https://www.yoctoproject.org/docs/2.1/dev-manual/dev-manual.html#using-bbappend-files

Comment: I would want to avoid bbappend files, so they would stay separate.

Comment: But this is not how Yocto works. You change recipes in other layers with bbappends in your layer.

Comment: @vladcocos check SSTATE_ALLOW_OVERLAP_FILES

Answer (score 0):

You can use the variable `SSTATE_ALLOW_OVERLAP_FILES` in order to achieve this. However, in most cases, implementing a .bbappend file is a better strategy.